# According to the Quran, is man created from a clot of blood?

Tags: tafseer, creation, surat-al-alaq

In the very first revelation on the prophet in Cave of Hira, when the light (Gabriel) spoke the to prophet for the first time, I see a technical difficulty, when Gabriel said, God created man from a clot of blood. This is not true. Blood has no role in creation of human being. Why it was said, man was created from a clot of blood? This is surah 96 verse 1-3

```
Shakir
Read in the name of your Lord Who created.

Shakir
He created man from a clot.

Shakir
Read and your Lord is Most Honorable
```

Comment: I don't see the word "blood" in your translation.

Comment: it is supposed to be clot of blood. But what is clot then if it is not blood.

Comment: And how do you know it is a clot of blood? Do you even know if clot is a one-to-one translation of "'alaq"?

Answer (score 5):

If you see sahih international the translation says "clinging substance".

The word used in the Quran is `عَلَقٍ` (alaq), which would denote "hanging" or "clinging".

It also has roots to `علقة` (alaqah), which would mean a "leech" (which is a worm that hangs or clings to its host and sucks blood).

Below are the images of a leech and embryo.

Between the 37th and 44th day (16 - 17 - 18 in image), the embryo looks similar to a leech. The embryo also acts like a leech by clinging on its host and drawing its nutrition from its host.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation but google translation says [clot](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/اقْرَأْ%20بِاسْمِ%20رَبِّكَ%20الَّذِي%20خَلَقَ%0Aخَلَقَ%20الْإِنسَانَ%20مِنْ%20عَلَقٍ)

Comment: Yes but if you paste the word only 'عَلَقٍ' , it says "hang" or "cling". http://translate.google.com/#ar/en/%D8%B9%D9%8E%D9%84%D9%8E%D9%82%D9%8D

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter - Google translate is one of the worst places to look for an accurate linguistic translation.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter How do you expect to be scientific and use a tool that translates modern Arabic for classical Qur'anic Arabic?

Comment: @Muz its not a tool for newbies , rather some one who has some working knowledge of both languages. i normally use it to translate single words or a few sets of words

Comment: I am not using goole translation as reference. To me more accurate translation is by shakir and others but that translation also says clot. Clot does not mean leach btw. Hanging substance is probably wrong translation because just like blood is not mention, substance is also not mentioned.

Comment: lol.... first you say...."google says it is clot".....then you say "i dont use google as reference"......  make up your mind and open a question about the arabic word alaq as clot vs leech.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter The accurate translation for the word alaq is what islam101 is mentioned. [see](http://www.ejtaal.net/m/aa/#HW=652,LL=5_417,LS=2,HA=506,LS_HIDE)